# list.js not working on dynamically created elements created dynamically using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a sortable list using list.js on [codepen](http://codepen.io/S-Lynne/pen/xZEaRe?editors=101). The following is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<h1>FCC News Viewer</h1>
<div id="users">
    <form id="searchbox">
      <input type="form" class="search" id="magnifying_glass"></input>
    </form>
  <div id="sort-by">
    <button class="sort" data-sort="date">Sort by date</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="rank">Sort by rank</button>
    <button class="sort" data-sort="author">Sort by author</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(json) {
    for (i=0; i<Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
      $('ul').append("<li class='article'><img src="+json[i].author.picture+"\><a href="+json[i].link+" class='headline'>"+json[i].headline+"</a><br><a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/"+json[i].author.username+" class='author'>"+json[i].author.username+"</a><p class='rank_text'>"+"&hearts;"+"<span='rank'>"+json[i].rank+"</span></p><p class='date'></p></li>")
      if (i == Object.keys(json).length-1) {
        var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'date', 'rank', 'author' ]
        };
        var userList = new List('users', options);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

I have both the jquery and list.js libraries loaded. When I press any of the sort buttons, three elements of the 100 I created move and not even according to the sorting category. Is there something more to creating a sortable list that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed an issue with the opening and closing quotes (double and single), also date should be included in the options, and even though I did not find it explicitly written in the documentation, it seems that the sorting class should be attached to an immediate child of the li item - this is what fixed rank sorting for me. This is how I have adjusted your codepen js:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(json) {
    for (i=0; i<Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
      $('ul').append(
        "<li class='article'>" + 
        "<img src='" + json[i].author.picture + "' /'>" + 
        "<a href='" + json[i].link + "' class='headline'>" + 
        json[i].headline + 
        "</a><br>" + 
        "<a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/" + json[i].author.username +
        "' class='author'>" + json[i].author.username + "</a>" +
        "<p class='rank'>&hearts;<span='rank-span'>"
        + json[i].rank + "</span></p><p></p></li>");

      if (i == Object.keys(json).length-1) {
        var options = {
          valueNames: [ 'rank', 'author' ]
        };
        var userList = new List('users', options);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh! It was because of my missing single quotes on the links. That makes so much sense. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest not mixing in any HTML code in the Javascript file. What you have is considered obtrusive. I would redefine the problem after you have factored out the HTML that is embedded in the Javascript, this can lead to some very messy and hard to understand code. The separation of presentation and behavior is very important.

Please see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Here is the section of code concerning this:

```
$('ul').append(
"<li class='article'><img src="+json[i].author.picture+"\>
<a href="+json[i].link+" class='headline'>"+json[i].headline+"</a>
<br><a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/"+json[i].author.username+" class='author'>"+json[i].author.username+"</a>
<p class='rank_text'>"+"&hearts;"+"<span='rank'>"+json[i].rank+"</span></p><p class='date'></p></li>")
```

Comment: I did that because I thought it would be more dynamic. If the API creator added additional items to the array I wanted it to update automatically. Is there a way to do this with separate HTML and Javascript?

Comment: Yes there is, this is actually what something Handlebars is very good for. [link](http://handlebarsjs.com/) It allows you to separate that invasive HTML, while keeping your logic kept in a JS Function. So your view will have any dynamic associations via the provided templates. ex:            `<img src="+json[i].author.picture+"\> ` would become      `                                                                                       `<img src= "{{ thisInstead }}"\> `

Comment: Just to clarify the above, the second snippet                                           `<img src= "{{ thisInstead }}"\>` would be in the view ( HTML )